# Android Reading and Writing int[] Arrays from Local Storage

Tags: android, file-io, storage

I've got a game that tracks the user's scores over time. There are 20 different game modes which need to be kept distinct.

My question is: what is the simplest means to read the scores from storage for the proper game mode, and update them each time the user finishes new game?

I believe the possibilities are:

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- Database: never worked with, would prefer to avoid

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Android's docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html),

- Use Shared Preferences for primitive data
- **[Use internal device](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) storage for private data**
- Use external storage for large data sets that are not private
- **[Use SQLite databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for structured storage** *[Personally, I would do this though, as you could create a table that has a row for each game mode, and store the score accordingly]*

**EDIT**: As to how you should go about organizing your data with internal storage, you could have a file for each game mode and save the score in it, or have each line of one file be a game mode and the score for it.